# Find a global bound for $\beta$ of the regularized logistic objective

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I  have this cost function
$$
f(x)= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \log(1+\exp(\langle a_i, x\rangle)) \right) + \frac{\lambda}{2}\|x\|^2. 
$$ $a_i$ is the i'th row of some matrix $A$. I know that $f$  is convex.

I need to show that $ \| \nabla f(y) -  \nabla f(x) \| \le \beta \| y-x\| \;\;\; \text{for all}\;  x,y \in R^n , \text{for some}\;  \beta > 0 \in R$

I computed :

$ \nabla \frac{\lambda}{2}\|x\|^2 = \lambda x $

$ \nabla [ \log(1+\exp(\langle a_i, x\rangle) ] = \frac{ \exp(\langle a_i, x\rangle)}{ 1+ \exp(\langle a_i, x\rangle)} a_i $

$ \nabla [\left( \sum_{i=1}^n \log(1+\exp(\langle a_i, x\rangle) \right)+ \frac{\lambda}{2}\|x\|^2  ] = Z(x)  +\lambda x $

Where $Z(x) =  \sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{ \exp(\langle a_i, x\rangle)}{ 1+ \exp(\langle a_i, x\rangle)} a_i $

$ \| \nabla f(y) -  \nabla f(x) \|  = \| Z(y) - Z(x) + \lambda  (y-x) \| \le \| Z(y) - Z(x)\| + \lambda \|y-x\| $

But now I'm not sure how to proceed. I want to bound $\| Z(y) - Z(x) \| $ by some constant times $\| y-x \|$ but not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

If the Hessian of $f$ is bounded, then the gradient is globally Lipschitz.

The Hessian of $x \mapsto {1 \over 2} \|x\|^2$ is $I$

Verify that the function $\phi(t) = \log(1+e^t)$ is convex and the second derivative (Hessian) is bounded.

It is straighforward using the composition rule to check that the Hessian of $x \mapsto \phi(a^T x)$
is $\phi''(a^Tx) a a^T$, which is bounded.

Comment: But how do I know what is the $\beta$ ?

Comment: A little work shows that $\phi'' \le {1 \over 4}$, so ${1 \over 4} \sum_k \|a\|^2 + \lambda$ would work. A little more work shows that this is the best bound.

Comment: (Assuming I have made no mistakes, a bit presumption.)

Comment: So the L2 norm of the Hessian matrix is the bound on  $\beta$ ?

Comment: The induced $2$ norm. It is the mean value theorem applied to the gradient.